# "call_state_offhook list.size()==0 number is null" when I call someone with my Samsung Galaxy S9

Tags: calls, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I see a warning:

> "call_state_offhook list.size()==0 number is null"

whenever I call someone with my Samsung Galaxy S9. What is the issue and how can I stop seeing this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

after installing a call recorder, have same message

Comment: Thanks,. I guess it's the call recorder that causes the message

Answer (score 0):

I found it was due to my call recorder app, uninstalling and reinstalling made no difference. I had to go into settings, then apps, click on the app and storage, followed by clear data. This resolved the issue.